# What's the fobi form url? And how do I embed it in another template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using Django-fobi, and I don't know how to do the following:
1) get a url for sharing the form without allowing a user to edit the form
2) include the form in another existing template

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Only authors of the form are able to edit it.
- Regarding embedding the form in another existing template, that part isn't difficult, read the docs. It's all about rendering the form. Otherwise integration with third party packages wouldn't be possible. See [this](https://django-fobi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#rendering-forms-using-third-party-libraries).